# How to show refresh indicator during an ajax refresh call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have some jQuery code working that reloads the div every `10 seconds` without reloading the whole page. However, right at the moment, the user doesn't see anything happen on the browser when the refresh is happening.

I know there are thousands of examples on the internet, but I want for the script I already have to display a loading gif image while the data is retrieved when the refresh is happening every 10 seconds for me, user should see some refresh image like this -

[image].

I'm sure this is probably easy, but I can't find any info on how to do it. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

**Problem Statement:-**

Below is my div in my JSP file `(dataInfo.jsp)` and I am reloading the div `container` every 10 seconds without reloading the full page.

```
<body>
    <div id='headerDivDash'>
        <h1 id='topHeaderDash'>
          <!-- some image here -->
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div id="vertical-list" style='display: block; list-style-type: none;'>
        <ul class="resp-tabs-list">
            <a href="_blank"><li>Test 1</li></a>
            <br />
            <a href="_blank"><li>Test 2</li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- just need to reload this div, other div should be intact without getting appended -->
    <div class="container">

    </div>
    <div class="footer">Some Value Here</div>
</body>
```

Now below is the jquery script I am using to load the `div container` every 30 seconds and it works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var auto_refresh = setInterval(
        function ()
        {
        $('.container').html('');
        $('.container').load('dataInfo.jsp .container').fadeIn("slow");
        }, 10 * 1000);

    });
</script>
```

Now as I mentioned above, as soon as the refresh is going to happen, I would like to grey out the `container div` and show refresh image as shown above and as soon as the refresh is done, then show the normal result and then the refresh image will also be gone..

Is this possible to do in my current example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you are already using JQuery so this answer will suit you well.
You can use this code to create the gray background and show the loading image.

```
// Create a refresh function:
function refresh(){
    // SHOW overlay
    $('#overlay').show();
    // Retrieve data:
    $.ajax({
        url: 'data.html',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
            // onSuccess take only the container content
            var content =  $($.parseHTML(data)).filter(".container"); 
            //Replace content inside the div
            $('.container').html(content);
            // HIDE the overlay:
            $('#overlay').hide();
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    // Create overlay and append to body:
    $('<div id="overlay"/>').css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: '100%',
        height: $(window).height() + 'px',
        opacity:0.4, 
        background: 'lightgray url(http://bradsknutson.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/page-loader.gif) no-repeat center'
    }).hide().appendTo('body');

    // Execute refresh with interval:
    setInterval(refresh, 1 * 1000);
});
```

Hope this help you. Note: Replace "img/loading.gif" with the route to the gif you want to use.

Here you go with the code working:
http://jsbin.com/zizudexo/1/edit

Comment: Thanks. So with your example I should remove my jquery call right? And just use yours? Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, thats correct :) erase it all and replace it with this code. Give me some love with your vote please.

Comment: It works fine after replacing `data.html` with `dataInfo.jsp`.. but there is one problem. As you can see, I have other divs as well. I have header and footer div as well. So what is happening currently is, with your code, when it is refreshing container div, it is appending all other divs and after refresh, I can see multiple divs appended together on my browser.. Not sure how to fix it.. Any thoughts?

Comment: I guess the url portion in your jquery example has to be change somehow.. bcoz it will load the whole page..

Comment: What is it appending to the other divs? Can you show me an example code of the appends please? Did you changed anything to the code?

Comment: nopes. I didn't change any code, I just added your code by replacing mine... After refresh, I can see two headers and two footers on my browser.

Comment: That might be because the page you want to load has them. Just put the data inside the page you are loading, don´t put all the header and footer tags.

In my code I just replace the data inside the container so if you load a page with a header in it, it will append inside the container.

Comment: I see.. But I need to use header and footer as well.. Is there any way, I can just refresh the container div? :(

Comment: Yes, I change the data inside the container only. The page you are loading, does it has a header and footer too? That might be the problem, the page you are loadin with ajax doesn´t need header nor footer.

Comment: Yeah it has header and footer too as well as shown in the question in my jsp file.. You can see one div before `container div` and another div just below container div in my above question.

Comment: Changed my code, the refresh method, now it will just get the container content and fill the container with it.

Comment: Yeah it works fine now.. Thanks a lot man.. Appreciated your help.

Comment: You're welcome. What you are trying to do isn´t the best aproach but well, you asked for it. I would recommend just loading a page without header nor footer with ajax. You will save some bytes in the file transfer. (Recommendation). Don´t load it all up again, load a page with just the new content inside of it.

Comment: one more thing on this, how do I use the absolute path of an image instead of using the url directly as you have shown above? Because in our production system, it will block access to this url because of firewall issue.

Comment: Download the image and then put it a relative path. Nothing new. Just call the img from your servers.

Answer (score 2):

When you start the ajax request, place the loading image on the results container.

```
$('<div id="ajaxLoad"></div>').appendTo('.container');
```

Add this CSS rule, to display it correctly:

```
#ajaxLoad {
    position: absoulte;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background: silver url(my_image.png) no-repeat center center;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Add a `position: relative;` to the `.container`.

Then you can start the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "dataInfo.jsp",
    success: function(data) {
        $('.container').html(data).fadeIn("slow");
    },
    complete: function() {
        $('#ajaxLoad').remove();
    }
});
```

When the data arrives display it, thats what success does. The complete runs even when the server returns an error code or your query times out.

Comment: Thanks lionel, in your example, it will load the whole `dataInfo.jsp` page which means other div will get appended as well. How do I just load the container div only after every refresh to avoid div getting appended.

Comment: It would be the best to retrieve only the needed parts of the text from the server. However if its not possible, maybe you can parse the response with jquery in the `success` function: `data = $(data).find('.content').html();`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you look at this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/siva_hari/659zm/)

I used `<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>` fontawesome icon to show refresh symbol... 
This is one of the ways to achieve what you want...